# Javascript or Jquery Posting of data to ASP.NET from an html element defined in Javascript then getting the returned value and displaying it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

**I am required to use .Net 3.5 and This is what I have so far**

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="chooseElecDiv.aspx.cs" Inherits="chooseElecDiv" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Choose</title>
    <script src="js/classManipulator.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div class="w-container header">
            <div class="w-section w-clearfix header-section">
                <div class="header-link">Logout</div>
                <div class="header-link">Manage</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="w-container const-cont">
            <div class="w-section const-section">
                <div id="const-details" class="const-details"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="w-container selection-cont">
            <div class="w-section selection-section">
                <div class="w-row selection-row">
                    <div id="opts-sel" class="w-col w-col-3 selected-col">

                    </div>
                    <div id="sel-opts" class="w-col w-col-9 options-col">

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>            
    </form>
</body>
```

**Javascript: located in js/classManipulator.js**

Posts the value as json to ASP.NET

```
function saveAddresses() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chooseElecDiv.aspx/saveAddresses",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
}
function OnSuccess(data) {
    alert(data);
}
function OnError(data) {
    alert(data);
}


window.onload = function(){
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    addMyClass(form, "ps-form");
    form.setAttribute("data-name", "Email Form");
    form.id = "email-form";
    form.name = "email-form";
    document.getElementById("const-details").appendChild(form);

    /*THIS CREATES THE BUTTON AND ADDS IT TO A PREVIOUSLY DEFINED FORM*/
    var saveButton = document.createElement("input");
    saveButton.setAttribute("data-wait", "Please wait...");
    saveButton.setAttribute("runat", "server");
    saveButton.type = "button";
    saveButton.value = "Save";
    saveButton.id = "savebtn";
    form.appendChild(saveButton);
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", saveAddresses);
}
```

**ASP.NET**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace ASPLoadDataJquery
{ 
    [MetadataType(typeof(chooseElecDiv))]
    public partial class chooseElecDiv : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string SaveAddresses()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "Hello tks";
    }

}
```

}

I would like to be able to send the json data to ASP.NET and have ASP.NET process and confirm receipt by responding.

How do I get C# to detect the post request from the button without using elements defined as ASP.NET objects and processing them directly with the code behind?

How do I get ASP.NET to receive the data that is posted as json?

**I get error**

```
Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:
Line 18: { 
Line 19:     [MetadataType(typeof(chooseElecDiv))]
Line 20:     public partial class chooseElecDiv : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: ASP.NET `Page` class works with its own data i.e. controls on `.aspx` page. It is better and easier to send AJAX requests to `.asmx` web service or WCF service (`.svc`). Both are supported by .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the aspx page header. Should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="chooseElecDiv.aspx.cs" CodeFileBaseClass="ASPLoadDataJquery.chooseElecDiv" Inherits="ASPLoadDataJquery.chooseElecDiv" %>
```

As for ajax calls to the back end you are on the right track [WebMethod] is the key.

Preferred way to write the page header tag would actually be.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="ASPLoadDataJquery.chooseElecDiv" Codebehind="chooseElecDiv.aspx.cs" %>
```

Im guessing this web application was converted from a web site at some point.